# Can we please have a few additions to the toolbar?

Tags: discussion, fun, toolbar, design

I humbly request the following toolbar buttons when composing a new question:

[image: New buttons...lotsa buttons....ugly buttons :(]

Notice the addition of four new buttons. I will briefly describe their functions below:

- **Freehand circle button** - automatically infers (based on context) where a freehand circle needs to be placed within the picture immediately preceeding the cursor.
- **Insert Jon Skeet's profile** - inserts a link to Jon Skeet's profile (what did you expect?).
- **Unicornify page** - Generates a hash of the current contents of the question and passes it off to the wonderful [Unicornify](http://unicornify.appspot.com/) service.
- **Waffle** - not implemented yet - *should be complete within 6 - 8 weeks*

---

**Note:** I may have missed some buttons when planning, so please add any you think I missed.

Comment: **WHO MADE** `[always-friday-in-iceland]` **A SYNONYM FOR** `[fun]` **?!?!?!**

Comment: @Jon Since it was done by popular demand, I'd say everyone made the synonym.

Comment: @Jon: I just noticed that!!!! Shame on them!

Comment: @Grace Note don't drag me into this. Only four people had to approve that change, and I wasn't one of them. [I'm with Jon](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/always-friday-and-fun).

Comment: The Unicornify icon should use the person's unicorn avatar, not a generic one.  Can't get enough of mine's googly eyes.

Comment: -1 No freehand circles.

Comment: @Jon: **LOOK AT THE FIRST BUTTON!!!**

Comment: The button is part of the UI. It can't possibly be a freehand circle.

Comment: @Jon: the RED button :)

Comment: @George: What he means is, a button of a freehand circle is not a freehand circle in and of itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### ):

This button changes all backwards smilies in StackExchange™ ForwardLooking ApprovedSmilies™. Useful for quick fixing of heretically-aligned smilies.

Alternative icon: [image: rchern]

Comment: +1 - just for the icon alone.

Comment: How offensive! ):

Comment: Why is your smiley using a happy `)` then? Oh, sorry, I read it wrong..

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `jQuery` button! It inserts jQuery code, which always be used:

```
$
jQuery
$
```

Comment: Well, when composing questions, that doesn't really make sense... :)

Comment: [A++, would code again](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/a-would-code-again)

Comment: @George: Blasphemy! What is this "When doing *x* jQuery doesn't really make sense..." you speak? I thought jQuery was **always** the answer!

Comment: But it can't answer a question that hasn't been asked... can it?

Comment: @George: Yes thanks. Answer updated :-)