# Careers 2.0 Featured Listing: Web company needs successor for retiring unicorns

Tags: discussion, april-fools

You know [what day is coming up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day), right? Just to get you up to speed:

- Stack Overflow's [first April Fool's day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20477/the-fancy-and-amazing-april-fools-question) came with glitter, cornify buttons, lots of pink, and Comic Sans.
- Last year, [all user avatars turned into unicorn images](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/reminder-its-april-1st/), provided by a web service created by some weirdo with too much free time.

So, what about 2011? Well, while we do have some ideas, we'd be stupid not to ask the probably largest accumulation of… special… creativity on the Internet – and that's obviously Meta*!

So, offer your ideas! Of course you won't know until April 1st what actually happens (and we don't promise anything), but be sure that we plan to reward great ideas with a little more than just a Meta rep bounty!

Except that your suggestions should be a) funny (at least in the eyes of most people), b) doable, and c) awesome, there are no restrictions. C'mon get crazy!

<sub>*cue obligatory "the sites are run by you" :)</sub>

Comment: Changing reputation scoring once again would be nigh hilarious

Comment: Cut everybody's rep in half, and close Meta for the day.

Comment: Multiple all gained rep * a random negative number for that day, that will surely scare some users :P

Comment: Captcha lottery: Those who guess both words are automagically moderators

Comment: Open **PoliticsOverflow** and forbid **subjective and argumentative**** questions. Everything closed :)

Comment: Hadn't this ought to be CW?

Comment: The first April Fool's Day also had a side project proposed on UserVoice of everyone changing their names to Jon Skeet for the day. Not too many people actually went through with it. I couldn't bring myself to actually answer a question before I changed back.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: I thought we finally got the community wiki police off of Meta. I guess not... Anyway, let people get some reps for their good ideas, at least for a while. This'll be auto-CW'ed because of answer count in no time anyway.

Comment: @George: just post another 10 suggestions. DO IT FOR THE LULZ!!!

Comment: I just passed 15k rep thanks to this question. And this is a question in need of protection if I ever saw one....

Comment: @Ivo I see the question coming in SO: **What is a random negative number?**

Comment: @belisarius `var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + min) + 1); alert(-rand + ' is a random negative number.');`

Comment: @Nyusz It was language-agnostic !

Comment: This is too small to be the official network-wide plan, but: post an unsolvable problem -- like my "solve P=NP" question from last year -- and attach a 100k rep bounty.

Comment: The time is right. Let's [bring back the dead.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81173/careers-2-0-featured-listing-web-company-needs-successor-for-retiring-unicorns/81271#81271)

Comment: @balpha, in all seriousness, I wonder whether whatever the joke ends up being, it might be best *not* to implement it on math.se

Comment: @Benjol, why is that?

Comment: @Benjol - If Math.SE doesn't want an April Fool's joke played on them, they should start lobbying against it on their meta, specifically requesting that the line, "Bring your sense of humor." be stricken from the FAQ.  Yes, a lot of people will be confused and frightened by the joke, but we're going to ask them to put up with it and embiggen their cultural awareness to include the silly American thing.  The day they remove teh funneh from stackexchange will be a sad day indeed.

Comment: Please note that in NO WAY will earnest users of the various sites be impeded in their usage of the site.  You'll still be able to ask questions, add answers, and vote.  The moderators and people who can vote to close won't allow any significant amount of fun having in terms of real questions and answers.  The question and answer pool won't be polluted.  And, frankly, if it's a problem for some users, will it really hurt them to take a break from the site for a day?

Comment: @jjnguy, well I guess their meta hasn't displayed a great sense of humour over the past months... and lots of silly arguments at cross-purposes with the "StackExchange overlords". I could be wrong, of course (I hope I am).

Comment: @Benjol, maybe this will help lighten them up! (or piss them off even more...)

Comment: maybe apply a dark theme...

Comment: @Benjol @jjnguy Having recently read through some of meta.math.se and math.se I now understand the point of your suggestion.  On the other hand, when your brother is so easily annoyed, it's wrong *not* to poke him once in awhile.

Comment: @Jin: I liked it. I really did.

Comment: @Pollyanna - I imagine that most users of Math.SE would be horrified to find that the FAQ contains the "bring your sense of humor" line.

Comment: We could forget who we are, anonymity for everybody.

Comment: @balpha - Alright, go ahead and accept http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81173/careers-2-0-featured-listing-web-company-needs-successor-for-retiring-unicorns/81376#81376 as the answer...

Comment: So I spent a god chunk of my workday looking for something interesting, but it appears to be just unicorns again.

Comment: Thanks @balpha (and whoever else worked on it) - this is awesome.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I think we could all use a little help with a variety of functions when we are composing questions and answers.

[image: Clippy presenting user with a list of choices concerning code formatting]

We'd need to generate several static images, and display them:

- randomly when a user is editing a post
- based on either keywords they enter
- based on buttons they press in the markdown editor
- ???

Nice thing is that it could apply to all sites across the board, rather than being programmer/geek specific.

Comment: Change the third example from `C` to `Perl` and you might have something there.

Comment: This makes me want to slap you.

Comment: "I see you're trying to ask a question about JavaScript.  Why not drop that and try jQuery?"  -Clippy

Comment: @Bill: "I see you're trying to ask a question. Why not drop that and try jQuery?" -Clippy"

Comment: @George: "I see that you're trying to ask a question and get Bill to use jQuery.  Why not drop that and try jQuery? -Clippy"

Comment: Needs more jQuery

Comment: Can we use jQuery to $.animate() clippy?

Comment: I think we need this for all users under 500 rep anyways :\

Comment: There goes my idea of proposing this as a _serious_ feature request.

Comment: @It's already been proposed, and I don't think it's been rejected, so there may still be hope...

Comment: Broken image link.

Comment: @badp I can see it. It's hosted on photo bucket, can you see photobucket.com?

Comment: @Adam Now I can see it again :)

Comment: @badp I strongly suspect that previously you were mentally blocking it out due to the horrible abuse you must have suffered at its hands.  Be at peace, it can harm you *no more.*

Comment: Isn't this already appearing in SU chat?

Comment: I'm the down vote.. I love this, but I love [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81173/careers-2-0-featured-listing-web-company-needs-successor-for-retiring-unicorns/81199#81199) even more :) Since the end is near, and all ...

Answer (score 76):

EBay-style premium listings!

[image]

Comment: I want fries and a shake with *my* gravatar.

Comment: I <3 this - but make it cost rep

Comment: You forgot the $1.00 option where it's stamped with Jon Skeet's seal of approval.

Comment: So, how much should we charge for allowing the use of <blink>?

Comment: Each answer comes with 1 free code block.  Additional codeblocks: $1

Comment: This could be a fundraiser!

Comment: @balpha, no amount of money in the world would justify such a thing.

Comment: @balpha, replacing `<strong>` with `<blink>` for the day would be... fun, too!

Comment: I like a little <blink> in my <marquee><marquee direction="left">.

Comment: All money goes to a charity

Comment: @Pierre actually making it a working form is a great idea, but is likely to create tax problems and paperwork I assume... Maybe redirect the user to a "APRIL FOOL'S" page but plant a link to a number of charities who would be happy to accept the money instead?

Comment: Ban Jon Skeet from submitting a competing answer $34.99

Comment: @mootinator let Jon Skeet answer but **attribute it to me** $124.99

Comment: Can anyone post the freehand text? I can't read any of it past "Freehanded circles (up to 3/"

Comment: @Pop I think it says "up to 3 / post $2 or 5 waffles"

Comment: You totally forgot "Protection From Moderators ..... _$CALL_"

Answer (score 48):

Change all SO rep scores and counts to their **binary or hex representations** (depending on funny bone inclination).

Tell people it's a permanent change for programmers. Say something like "you spoke and we listened". Write a [creative blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) to support it. Make it witty and amusing.  I'm sure many people here can contribute awesome ideas to such a blog post.

If you have to keep the kids happy then at least keep any tooltip/alt tags as their actual base 10 number values.

Example of the binary version, mocked with Firebug:
[image]

Comment: Hex would be easier as it wouldn't overflow the layout and require layout changes.

Comment: @Pollyanna But it would be more fun if the reputation was overflowing everywhere, because you could never see how much reputation anyone has.

Comment: Thanks, now I miss the ever color changing envelope even **more**.

Answer (score 45):

I'm not sure how difficult it would be... but how about switching themes between sites? For example, give Stack Overflow the Programmers theme for a day, and vice versa. Or perchance do a three-direction with Stack Overflow getting Programmers, Programmers getting Meta Stack Overflow, and Meta getting normal Stack Overflow. You can then mix and match the sites for different interesting combos. Gaming ↔ Game Development, AskUbuntu ↔ Unix & Linux...

Not all of them have good matches (Seasoned Advice and Photography stand out, although I suppose using Photo's theme with a picture of a delicious meal wouldn't be entirely bad...), and there's nothing to swap between the Beta sites. But I figure, the idea was a mite humorous enough to toss out.

EDIT:
Five-minute mockup for Shog:

[image: the Seasoned Advice theme for Stack Overflow]

Comment: I think you stole my idea! :p

Comment: Seeing the Seasoned Advice theme on SO would be hilarious...

Comment: This would be absolutely hilarious, but possibly confusing to new visitors. Maybe show to registered users only?

Comment: Eh, just distribute the old Physics SE light-on-dark theme to all sites and call it a day.

Comment: I like the new logo, the only thing we should modify is the `t`, it should be a `l` for Slack Overflow.

Comment: Snack Overflow?

Comment: @Popular And then leave it that way. Forever

Answer (score 44):

[image: Fake privilege bar]

Maybe some client-side generated blood-red @-notifications too while we're at it:

[image: blood-red notification]

Comment: Fixing Tim Stone *would* be a pretty funny joke.

Comment: OMFG THIS IS AWESOME

Comment: haha this is fantastic and doable!

Answer (score 42):

> Stack Exchange, Inc is going public!
>
> As our show of thanks to you providing all the great content for Stack Overflow, we're allowing you the one time opportunity to convert your reputation points into actual company stock.
>
> This is a one-way transaction and any points converted will be deducted from your reputation and show on your user history and graph as "SOIS buy-in"

And create a page that shows how much stock they would get for whatever amount they want to pony up.

Comment: Ha, that would be awesome!

Comment: Better yet: shutting down 'cause they were bought out by Oracle for internal mailing list uses

Comment: +1 for Oracle reference.

Comment: This...is...STACKOVERFLOW! Therefore, `s/pony/unicorn/`

Answer (score 31):

Hide the accepted answer behind an ["INSTANT ACCESS TO THIS SOLUTION"](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Windows/Q_25766539.html) banner... which vanishes as soon as you mouse anywhere near it.

Or announce a merger with Experts Exchange.

EDIT: Okay, so it looks like I wasn't the only one with ideas around EE. Oh well.

Comment: The instant access thing is new though. Could be combined :)

Answer (score 28):

I've seen a number of people talking about rep, requiring rep for asking, changing downvotes to cost different amounts of rep, etc...

**What about if we just decide reputation points were a bad idea and drop them altogether?**

No more rep shows up. Anywhere. Could be done pretty easily using CSS. Combined witha  blog post about how wrong we all were this whole time, and our new grand vision for an "everyone is equal, every question and answer equally good!" StackExchange.

To clarify, that's the *joke*. Rep doesn't *actually* go away, it's still here and works exactly the same as always. So I'm not proposing to change how Rep *works*, just pretend it's gone.

Comment: How 'bout we decided messing with rep (or anything that materially prevents the normal operation of the site) is a bad idea for april fools and drop it altogether?

Comment: If folks think they got a free ride in downvoting, then this might upset people the next day too...?

Comment: @Joel: Point taken. I was of course not meaning rep would go away, it would still be there and work exactly like normal. It would just be hidden. But on second thought, it probably is too drastic. As @Arjan said, it might cause people to think it was really gone and act badly.

Comment: I like this. April Fools' Jokes are supposed to overstep limits to *some* extent, and this would do no permanent damage. Most people would go to Meta or the Blog to express their outrage, and could be quickly educated that things will be back to normal in 24 hours. Fulfills the very definition of an April Fools' joke to me @Joel

Comment: I think this is my favourite, because apart from the hilariousness, it may give us some insights in how voting works when you don't see users' rep scores

Comment: @Pekka actually that is a very good point, I hadn't even considered that!

Answer (score 27):

How about adding the moderator diamond ♦ next to the logged in user's name all over the site (only visible to the user himself)?

Comment: For added lulz, add a link to a fake moderator tools page and count the number of hits it gets.

Comment: @Bill, good idea. And afterwords ban everyone where that page didn't get even a single hit ;-)

Comment: Didn't reddit do this once?

Comment: @mmyers Last year.

Comment: I'd like a count of how many times Jeff's account gets suspended or deleted.

Answer (score 24):

[image: accept rate changed to sparkly]

Comment: This could definitely be implemented alongside one or more of the other suggestions. It's not really enough by itself, but it's definitely the same flavor as cornify and unicorn avatars.

Comment: Reminds me of that episode of South Park where the girls ranked the boys by cuteness... "does that sparkle with everyone?"

Answer (score 23):

Cover the sites in advertisements for the [upcoming movie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67008/are-rumors-of-a-film-true-i-hope-so-by-golly).

Comment: There we go! That's a good idea... but then we'll need to have a special site for the movie...

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Hmm, I don't know what we'd do about the site itself, but clearly the promo game should be [Robot Unicorn Attack](http://games.adultswim.com/robot-unicorn-attack-twitchy-online-game.html).

Answer (score 22):

Facebook integration.

Comment: What a... special idea!

Comment: I am afraid many, many users will not get the joke :)

Comment: @belisarius: those are the *best* kind of jokes...

Comment: @Shog _That_ was the intention behind the ":)" and the +1

Comment: @belisarius: On Meta, we use ellipses to stand in for emoticons. (And "yo momma" insults. Context is everything...)

Comment: My ellipses101 would come after my pending English101 **:)**

Comment: Fark did it for April Fools' a year or two ago. Sorry.

Answer (score 22):

Take the "Stack Overflow Is You" motto to the extreme and instead of a Stack Overflow logo at the top, have a logo that is "*n* overflow" where *n* is the user's name.  Adding the User's Gravatar (as recommended by Pekka) seems like a cool idea too (though not if it screws up loading time).

Or, replace all accepted answers' user name and links with Jon Skeet's name and profile link.

Comment: Nice! Maybe even with the user's gravatar (if it's a photograph).

Comment: +1 for the Jon Skeet part - Why not turn that into "Stack Overflow is Jon" then?

Answer (score 22):

People joke that Jon Skeet can answer questions before they are asked.

How about you generate some fake content using [Flack Overstow](https://stackapps.com/questions/306/flack-overstow-generate-spam-from-trilogy-posts) and auto post an answer by Jon (or someone else?, maybe the leader in the tag) and date the post a few minutes before the question was asked.

Comment: or just feature Jon's answers and have it subtract five minutes from all of his posts (or edits too!) when displaying?

Comment: Nice! I like this very much.

Comment: @drach, The only issue with that is Jon doesn't participate in every question.  Only a subset of users would see the joke.

Comment: It would definitely be worth expanding beyond one user. Maybe for any answer that gets more than 1 upvote?

Comment: @Pekka, that would be interesting.  Although, I wonder how many people would notice time stamp oddities.

Comment: @pekka ~ So extend all posts which are not questions (same table, ya?) to have -1 hour for the day, it's a display trick, not a table update

Comment: @jinguy the answer is to always use jQuery anyway...

Comment: I would like to note that SE already has answers dated before the question. For example, on Meta SE, we have https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22622/222298 "How would you motivate your colleagues to join StackOverflow?" which is from weeks before the question was asked.

Answer (score 21):

Quora was right all along:

- Unlock favourite/ignored tag editing for all users.

  - **+2** rep per suggested interesting topic.
  - All suggested interesting topics are automatically accepted. No exceptions.
- Followers!

  - You can follow people by starring them.
  - **+10** per follow.
  - **−2** per unfollow.
  - To kickstart things generate many followings at random.
  - Follow at **10** reputation
  - Unfollow at **125** reputation
- Formatting!

  - Markdown is too hard. Get rid of it.
  - Replace it with an intuitive WYSIWYG editor. You cannot see or edit source, because HTML is *so* web 1.0.
  - Ban evil outbound links outside the site; URL copy and paste ought to be enough for everybody.
- Janitors!

  - Moderators are *so* web 2.0; get rid of them.
  - Closing sucks; retag instead.
  - Janitors can super downvote: **+2** reputation for the voter, **−10** for the votee.
  - Become a janitor at **1000** reputation.
- Notifications! Drop down a message every time:

  1. A post of yours was upvoted.
  2. A post of a follower's was upvoted.
  3. A follower upvoted a post.
  4. A post of yours was downvoted.
  5. A post of a follower's was downvoted.
  6. A follower downvoted a post.
  7. A post of yours was accepted.
  8. A post of a follower's was accepted.
  9. A follower accepted a post.
  10. A post of yours was commented.
  11. A post of a follower's was commented.
  12. A follower commented a post.
  13. A new question has been posted since you have loaded the page.
  14. A follower posts.
  15. A post of yours is answered by a follower's follower.
  16. A follower's question was answered.
  17. A follower was followed.
  18. A follower was unfollowed.
  19. A follower unlocks a privilege.
  20. You are followed.
  21. You are unfollowed.
  22. You gain reputation.
  23. You lose reputation.
  24. You would gain reputation, but a cap prevents that.
  25. A follower gains reputation.
  26. A follower loses reputation.
  27. A follower gains reputation, but a cap prevents that.
  28. A follower visits chat.
  29. A follower enters a chatroom.
  30. A follower posts a chat message.
  31. A follower stars a chat message.
  32. A follower flags a chat message.
  33. A follower is followed.
  34. A follower is unfollowed.
  35. A follower adds an interesting tag.
  36. A follower removes an interesting tag.
  37. A follower adds an ignored tag.
  38. A follower removes an ignored tag.
  39. <s>Jon</s> [*Somebody* has started typing an answer for the question you are viewing.](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=439226#439226)
  40. <s>Jon</s> *Somebody* has viewed a question of yours.
  41. <s>Jon</s> *Somebody* has started typing a question of yours.
  42. Oh, nevermind, <s>Jon</s> *Somebody* has stopped writing.

[image: NotificationOverflow]

Comment: "Drop down a message"? Is that how the cool kids are saying "Send an SMS" these days?

Comment: @Pop `notify.show("A follower has replied to a comment you posted. View your profile.")`

Comment: Yeah, I know what you _actually_ meant. But requiring users to provide phone numbers capable of receiving texts would be much more April Fool's-y.

Comment: Actually *implementing* all of this would be impossible, but I would like to see an entire screen full of all 21 bogus notifications. Care to do a mock-up?

Comment: Hey @Aarobot, I'm sorry but I could barely see your reply. I'll give you a screenshot as soon as I can display more than a line of text at a time... ah, [here we go](http://i.imgur.com/Yh5Ks.png)

Comment: That's a scary screenshot, its details might very well be real!

Comment: Ahahahahahahahahahahahaha! What a brilliant mockup.

Comment: Aces.  This should definitely be on our screens as of April 1st.

Comment: @George @balpha is a dev. He can do that

Comment: oh my god my eyes, what is this i don't even

Comment: @Pekka: Uh... how did you find that out?

Comment: @George I was kidding there, really, but with write DB access...

Answer (score 21):

Accidentally leak your server setup?

[image: Stack Overflow behind the scenes]

There's plenty of room for tweaking the exact links, of course. Entries like `adminPanel.htm` could link to all sorts of, uh, *non-standard* mod abilities; for example, a form that lets you punch in a user ID and see who has submitted flags against that user.

Comment: Nice, I like it! It would just obviously disrupt things a little too much if it came up for every request. Hmm, what would be an obvious but not too in-your-face way to bring a user to this page? Ideally they would feel like they've stumbled over something secret. Maybe a "debug" or "admin" button somewhere on the page that looks like they forgot to turn off development mode before building?

Comment: One of the secret documents would have to be about the planned migration of the code base to PHP for cost reasons, outlining the deep internal struggle within the organization.

Comment: No `.htpasswd` file? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan, there's an idea; disable user accounts for the day, just have a prompt that says "We simplified our system! Type in the username you want to use:" (and see how many people choose "Jon Skeet")

Comment: Wait... Apache? That *would* be funny because everyone knows that they use ISS.

Comment: Hilarious. It would give an interesting picture of how evil SO users are, too. How about appending all question URIs with randomly-generated versions of `&sql=select%20*%20from%20question%20where%20blah=blah` and see who takes the bait?

Answer (score 20):

I think this year you should customize the April Fool's jokes for each community.  Here are a few ideas:

- **Stack Overflow** - re-skin the site to match the style and layout of that hyphen site.
- **English Language & Usage** - Run the entire site through Google Translate to convert each question and answer to a random language.
- **Unix & Linux** - Make people enter answers at a command prompt.
- **Seasoned Advice** - Add a random [spam haiku](http://www.kbeamer.com/spam_haiku.html) answer to every new question.
- **Gaming** - You must beat 10 levels of *Angry Birds* to post a new question.

Comment: Ha, there are currently 23 live sites.  I think that would be a lot of work to implement 23 different pranks. (Although, those are good ideas)

Comment: ...and for Ask Ubuntu: make the site look like http://microsoft.com >:)

Comment: @George: You go too far, sir!  ;)

Comment: As for English: translating to some language *and back*, yielding some sort of English, might annoy people a lot. :-)

Comment: @Arjan ooooh yeah, auto-translate to chinese and back for every contribution!

Comment: but I don't _have_ Angry Birds!

Comment: On SU Clippy would offer help on every question :P

Comment: @badp: Someone's got to get busy on an *Angry Birds* Flash^H^H^H^H^H jQuery plugin.

Comment: Did you mean... jQuery plugin?

Comment: @badp: Fixed that.

Comment: @Bill Is it that much fun dissing the hyphen site?

Comment: Uh...what hyphen site? This is what it feels like to be out of the loop. Waaah.

Comment: @TheGuyWhoDisagreesWithYou Behold!  [The Dreaded Hyphen Site.](http://www.experts-exchange.com/)

Answer (score 20):

Instill paranoia into the answerers for the day. Make them quiver in fear for the whole day.

When just blindly viewing an unanswered question, have the avatar of the top user for one of its tags (or just the top user for the site, to make it computationally cheaper by bounds) show up in the corner, only to go away quickly or when the mouse approaches.

If the user still has the courage to work on an answer, pop down one of those banner notifications from the top to say the following, substituting a proper username.

> Be advised: Nick Craver has just answered this question while you were typing. It is probably hopeless for you to continue. Click here to refresh

Naturally, the refresh will not show anything. It may even show a "Haha!" or alternative point to show off what's going on, if you want to be generous.

---

For those who already are at the top, pester them with their rivals. Have Marc Gravell hot on the heels of Jon Skeet for *every* question he looks at. No peace of mind for the day!

Comment: Oh yeah! Maybe show an information bar for every question: "Be advised: Jon Skeet also opened this question 3s ago" picking the right user name would also be easy: Get some strong users from the user's 2-3 strongest tags. They are bound to know each other.

Answer (score 19):

This question was answered long before it was asked.

[Please Add Means of Converting Reputation to Actual Beer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70088/please-add-means-of-converting-reputation-to-actual-beer)

Comment: And snacks. Beer and snacks.

Answer (score 17):

[*Hot. Dog. Stand.*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34939/did-you-ever-wish-you-could-have-a-hot-dog-stand-themed-meta-stackoverflow-com)

Comment: This makes me want to un-slap you.

Answer (score 17):

```
/**
 * @author Jon Skeet
 * @author Adam Davis
 */
```

Display mockeries of infamous ads.

"Punch the unicorn to see if you win 500 reputation!"

"Lose that Google 15 with this one weird dieting tip."

Comment: Way to crib off of [Jon Skeet's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41181/script-to-remove-useless-so-content/41184#41184) to your question.

Comment: @popular His answer exhibits modularity, loose coupling, high cohesion, information hiding and separation of concerns.  It would be wrong *not* to reuse it.

Comment: Eff Tee Eff Wye.

Answer (score 15):

I'll borrow an idea from [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69524/can-we-please-have-a-few-additions-to-the-toolbar):

### Toolbar additions!

[image]

Answer (score 14):

I've had an idea brewing for months and it kind of continues the idea from last year.

Last year we changed everyone's Gravatar, this year, let's change their display name!!!

The idea is that a bunch of first names, last names, and suffixes are collected and then randomly combined to form the user's new name...

**Examples:**

- William van Smithstern the III
- Dr. Joseph Samuels Jr.
- *etc.*

Comment: In combination with doing this, they should also obscure diamonds for the day. It'll be like a masquerade ball where you can't even recognize the host.

Comment: @Grace: Ya, that would certainly help keep it mixed up.

Comment: Everyone is named either John Skeet, Marc Gravell, Joel Spolsky, or Jeff Atwood.

Comment: @Joel: ...or Geoffrey Chetwood :)

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: No! Don't name Jon Skeet's evil twin or he will *AAAAGH TOO LATE!*

Comment: What about [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39827/stack-overflow-has-too-many-men/39858#39858)?

Comment: @Joel **DOOOO IIIITTTT!!!** I literally laughed out loud when I read that. *So great!* (But add in "Rebecca Chernoff♦" for good measure :-)

Answer (score 13):

A **paywall** for all users with 500+ rep **for both asking and answering.**

Complete with a credit card form (29.98/month) and a link to a blog post outlining why this is totally not a sellout.

Of course, you just have to scroll down to continue!

Comment: Haha, they'd get sued by expert sexchange!

Comment: @Klaus: I'm wondering if that typo was intentional :P

Comment: Does the joke on the "other website" ever get old?

Comment: @Richardakacyberkiwi: No.

Answer (score 13):

How about some fake tag and badge sponsorships? "debugging" could be sponsored by Roach Motel. "Famous Question" could become "XHTML Regex parser". Etc.

[image: HTML tags lea͠ki̧n͘g fr̶ǫm ̡yo​͟ur eye͢s̸ ̛l̕ik͏e liq​uid pain, the song of re̸gular exp​ression parsing will exti​nguish the voices of mor​tal man from the sp​here I can see it can you see ̲͚̖͔̙î̩́t̲͎̩̱͔́̋̀ it is beautiful t​he final snuffing of the lie​s of Man ALL IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T ALL I​S LOST the pon̷y he comes he c̶̮omes he comes the ich​or permeates all MY FACE MY FACE ᵒh god no NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ]

Comment: Famous Question should be "the `<center>` cannot hold"

Comment: You are totally correct @Pollyanna, I will correct that when I update the image with more goodness

Comment: Here are a few other suggestions (images) if you're looking at it further then: Booster --> rocket image, civic duty --> saluting a flag, Cleanup --> mop and pail, Commentator --> Profile view of talking head and microphone, Critic --> Thumbs down, Deputy --> sheriff badge, Disciplined --> Whip, Enlightened --> eye of providence above pyramid on one dollar bill, Epic --> FTW

Comment: Thanks @Pollyanna, I'll edit those in later! Got a digest to finish now ;-)

Comment: I don't think [Zalgo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) likes to be rendered [using unknown glyphs](http://i.imgur.com/mz3dj.png)! (See also [Displaying Unicode on Chrome vs Firefox](http://superuser.com/questions/232636/displaying-unicode-on-chrome-vs-firefox).)

Comment: (And if your Unicode issues are on a Mac, then that is probably due to duplicate fonts installed with –a trial of– Microsoft Office. Please just shout if you need more details.)

Comment: Oh boy oh boy! We need hated companies to buy sponsored tags in order to boost their image among programmers (they're struggling to find good employees for their IT departments). BP and Tokyo Electric Power Company come to mind

Answer (score 12):

A notification bar pointing to a breaking story in the blog, written by Jeff or Joel, to this effect:

> The Stack Overflow team and the Venture Capitalists funding Stack Exchange have decided to provide additional funds in an unprecedented move to increase awareness  of StackOverflow, and encourage participation.
>
> **Reputation points  can be exchanged to money at a rate of $0.10 per point!**
>
> We plan to launch this some time this summer; however we will be **beta testing** this **today** until midnight GMT, or a maximum budget of up to $20,000, depending on what is reached first. **If you earn 100 rep points or more today**, a "claim my funds" button will appear in your user profile. Click it and follow instructions.
>
> All you need is a major credit card, or a PayPal account.

This would be the most hilarious variation of a general "Money for rep points today only!!!!1" idea, because it would keep people on their toes for a while.... If it's not too blatantly obvious.

Comment: Or a contact at Western Union?

Comment: THANK YOU BARRISTER IDRIS ENGA, I HAS RECEIVED MY MONIES FROM OUR PREVIOUS TRANSACTION, A+++++++++++++++++++++++++ WOULD ASSIST WITH UNSOLICITED INTERNATIONAL FINANCIAL TRANSACTION AGAIN

Comment: @POPULAR I AM SO GLAD TO HEAR THIS. UNFORTUNATELY MY DAUGTHER WAS HOSPITALIZED AND I WAS UNABLE TO REPLY. LOOKIGN FORWARD TO FUTURE TRANSACTIONS AND GOD BLESS AND NOBODY SHOULD TARNISH THE NAME OF WESTERN UNION

Comment: I stopped after reading $0.10 just to mentally figure out how much that would net me... This would totally work as an april fools joke.

Comment: `s/some time this summer/in six to eight weeks/` :-P

Answer (score 12):

Redirect randomly between all Stack Exchange sites.

Stack Overflow might wind up on Meta.SciFi, or AskDifferent could be on Unix & Linux.

Or integrate it with a Wheel of Redirects, like the Wheel of Migration that we mods use to decide where to send questions. <sup><sub>(oops, was that out loud?)</sub></sup>

Comment: *waves hands* there is no wheel of migration

Comment: Wheel of migration? I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: [LIES!](http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/pJaCJ/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 11):

Announce that you're closing the sites down because you were bought out by Experts Exchange.

Comment: That would *flood* SO **and** Meta with questions from morning to night.

Comment: @George: let 'em off the hook on Meta

Comment: +1 Also you may switch the buyer to Google (Groups?)

Comment: @belisarius Yeah.  Or Yahoo! Answers, as would be another good inside joke here on Meta.

Comment: "You will be redirected to EE in 30 seconds unless you click this link to stay at Stack Overflow."

Comment: @squill: Yahoo Answers... lol! That would make me furious :)

Answer (score 11):

To each question that already has at least one answer, automatically add an answer from Jeff Atwood, Joel Spolsky, Marc Gravell, Jon Skeet, or whoever else is in on the joke. Most of these answers should be *terrible*, yet appropriate to the question's tags.

- All JavaScript-tagged questions are [answered with jQuery-worship](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif).
- All HTML-related questions are answered by **bobince** asking if the user has tried using regex.
- All .NET questions get an answer from **Jon Skeet** suggesting that managed code isn't nearly fast enough for the task, and the user should try writing it in heavily-optimized FORTRAN. **Marc Gravell** responds with a comment about [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_Device).
- **Jeff Atwood** occasionally pops up to say that he once saw an answer on the hyphenated site, and the user should check over there. He doesn't explain what "the hyphenated site" is.
- **Joel Spolsky** [says something](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) [wise and insightful](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/HighNotes.html) [about the](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/FiveWorlds.html) [software business](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/SetYourPriorities.html) which has absolutely nothing to do with the question.
- Someone claiming to be **Eric Lippert** promises to bring the user's C# issue up at the next design meeting and create a special language feature to handle it.
- **Larry Wall** doesn't know the answer to your Perl question, but here's some [poetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Perl_pastimes) you might enjoy.
- **Alan Turing**, **Donald Knuth**, and **Charles Babbage** answer one question each. Turing suggests "some form of tape-fed computation device". Knuth's answer provokes a flamewar in the comments with **Edsger Dijkstra** about the merits of `goto`.

Only questions that already have an answer are affected, so it doesn't interfere with the question/answer process too much. Also, you could restrict it to questions that already have an accepted answer or an answer with a certain amount of upvotes. Obviously, protect the "answerers" from rep loss when "their" answers are downvoted to smithereens.

Comment: "downvoted to smithereens"? You misspelled "reflexively upvoted based on their usernames."

Comment: +1 I likes this! It's too late to do this this year, but it's a solid candidate for next year IMO. We'd need a whole host of editors standing by under the respective pseudonyms.

Comment: I love the idea, I'm worried that it might be detrimental to the real functioning of the site...

Comment: @rchern_sockpuppet419 - No more than one failed answer would be, and those happen. I think it's within the bounds of typical April Fools mayhem. :)

Comment: I want to impersonate Babbage!

Answer (score 10):

Make balpha's [Commander Keen Downvote](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oovHwrZaQwo) Script [native](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34903/stack-overflows-voting-system-is-not-entertaining-enough/41397#41397).

Comment: It's hilarious, but it'll encourage downvoting. I say make it an upvote script instead.

Answer (score 9):

You could make everyone think that the sites were [hacked by Anonymous](http://dagblog.com/media/anonymous-storm-gathering-let-it-rain-9181) by replacing every user name with "Anonymous" and every user image with:

[image]

Or:

[image]

Comment: Or maybe Guy Fawkes?

Comment: @mmyers: A good suggestion. Will add.

Comment: I wonder if anonymous would take it as a challenge.  How risk averse do you think SOIS is?  ;-D  Free security testing, and a great april fools joke to boot!

Comment: @Pollyanna: Everybody wins!

Comment: Meh, a bit too political.

Answer (score 9):

### Allow (fake) protesting of OP acceptance decisions

Add a button right below the green checkmark labeled <kbd>**PROTEST**</kbd> which pops up a message saying you can overrule the OP's decision to accept this answer at a cost of 30 rep points.

If the user accepts, redirect him to a page on the site where the protesting procedure — a clear scam for stealing half the user's rep points — is described, and a <kbd>confirm</kbd> button is displayed.

If the user confirms again, say

> Thank you. The answer will be un-accepted and your rep points deducted by tomorrow morning.

Comment: I'm going to say "un-accepted"

Comment: What would the scam be? Some kind of bounty thing?

Comment: @Justin I thought it more like a bet. If mods approve your decision, you lose 30 rep points and the answer is un-accepted. If mods deny, you lose half your rep. A fair game :)

Answer (score 9):

**BURN BURN BURN!!!** button

There's a limit to how much exposure to the low quality tab one can handle, after a while, noob-rage starts to take hold, and you start getting the urge to do more than just flag.

It would be cathartic to have a 'nuke' button with some satisfying animation effect to consign the likes of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164094/i-want-to-create-a-pop-2011-calendar-window-in-php-i-want-one-good-code-help) to oblivion, leaving a smouldering pile of ashes.

**EDIT** Add in a downvote, just to incentivate downvoting on stuff that deserves to die.

Comment: May I offer my first-born in support?

Comment: Something like http://i.imgur.com/NusRS.png? Pressing it flashes the question background red while a tiny missile fly in and after a moment the qusetion is destroyed.

Comment: @Tombull, exactly :)

Comment: Obviously this should be called the burninate button

Answer (score 9):

<sup>I'm totally in favor of Commander Keen [as suggested by Pollyanna](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81173/careers-2-0-featured-listing-web-company-needs-successor-for-retiring-unicorns/81376#81376), but nevertheless:</sup>

Ask users to participate in "a short" survey, and then continue asking questions until the user finally gives up? (The responses of the first 5 or 10 questions might actually be useful, if [the real survey](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/survey-says/) needs more data.)

Comment: "Unicorn-shaped cake made of waffles will be available at the conclusion of the survey. Thank you for helping us help you help us all."

Comment: I like this one.  After 10 or so generic questions about, say, demographics, it should start randomly picking out old question titles from the database and asking those as survey questions. (Possibly filtered to those with question marks to make it less obvious what's going on.)

Comment: @Aarobot, or questions from balpha's [Not a real question](http://notarealquestion.appspot.com/)!

Comment: those are the same questions.

Comment: Nice idea, but definitely promise a serious prize like an iPad or a netbook. Let the questions become more and more ridiculous (although I think they should be real survey questions, not ones from the database.) at some point, the user will leave in frustration. Then to round the joke, actually hold a draw among those who stayed on for more than 50 questions, and give away the real prize.

Answer (score 9):

Run the first annual Stack Exchange moderator [recall elections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recall_election).

Answer (score 8):

I think all the sites should be grayscaled ... not just the metas.

Or better might be to reverse the site colorations, from meta to the host, etc. Too simple, but also easy enough it should be doable.

Comment: `[status-completed]` on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 8):

Replace the term "Rep" with "Exp".

Comment: I thought this was funny at first glance, but it breaks Important Internet Rule #9 -- "don't feed the trolls" -- so -1.

Comment: @Popular Demand: That's rule *number 9* in your book? I thought it was like rule #3, right behind "don't believe everything you read on the internet" and "never reveal more about yourself on the internet than you conceivably want everyone everywhere to know about you forever". :-)

Comment: @TheOutOfStarsException: Well, to be fair, my rule #1 is "make up numbers at random for all other 'Important Internet Rules'; feel free to add, change or remove them at will."

Answer (score 7):

Have the community user bump/replay all the questions from last year, at the time same time of day that they were asked.

Answer (score 7):

jQuery Overflow.

When editing a question, after entering the title, the red banner (similar to the subjective warning) pops up: "It appears your question is about programming.  Have you totally dropped that and tried jQuery?"

Answer editing boxes are pre-fill with "You should totally drop that and try jQuery." (which will automatically go away once the user starts typing, and which won't allow the submit button to be pressed until they start typing, so we don't get this as an actual answer, but it appears anyway).

Answer (score 5):

When a user gets or gives their first up vote of the day they get a special Unicorn badge which links them to [this little game](http://www8.agame.com/mirror/flash/u/unicorn_coloring.swf) which is hosted on [agame](http://www.agame.com/)

It would of course require you to get permission to use the game but it would be worth it.

Also, add the Konami code for the day [and Cornify it up!](http://www.cornify.com/)

Comment: I like the Konami code idea.

Answer (score 5):

Launch a Q&A site for [Quora](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28422/quora).

I *did*, in fact, have April 1 in mind when I proposed it.

Comment: It sadly got closed, that was a good joke though.

Answer (score 5):

**Do Nothing**

MSO will be ablaze with users wanting to know what the joke was, expecting Unicorns or other such magic. Doing nothing is not a joke, and yet it is.

(the temptation was strong to put "troll" in this answer somewhere, as in "to troll").

Answer (score 5):

Every question gets the [unicorn](/questions/tagged/unicorn) tag.

Comment: How about every question *requires* the user to add the unicorn tag, but that tag not counted toward the upper limit of 5 tags per question.

Comment: @John K - Brilliance. How about a choice between either [unicorns], [ponies], or [jon-skeet]?

Answer (score 5):

Hide the envelope icon and watch the users freaking out, oh.. [wait](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope)..

Comment: the [eeeek](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope) question is gone 404

Comment: FYI it's still there for 10k users (@Alpine)

Answer (score 5):

Some new tags [no-really](/questions/tagged/no-really) and [im-serious](/questions/tagged/im-serious) and [come-on-you-guys](/questions/tagged/come-on-you-guys) to go along with this proposed tag:

[jon-skeet-only](/questions/tagged/jon-skeet-only) for those times when you only need Jon Skeet to answer you. And it will tag Jon Skeet so he sees your question as a priority item when he logs in. I suppose we could go so far as to introduce some others, for instance [grace-note-only](/questions/tagged/grace-note-only) or [pekka-only](/questions/tagged/pekka-only)

When you combine the first few tags with the latter one it pushes your tag to the top of the queue. Then there's the response tags:

[nuh-uh](/questions/tagged/nuh-uh) and [i-dont-think-so](/questions/tagged/i-dont-think-so) and [youre-wrong](/questions/tagged/youre-wrong) (which has synonyms [your-wrong](/questions/tagged/your-wrong) and [yer-wrong](/questions/tagged/yer-wrong) of course)

And in the spirit of helpfulness: [do-not-show-to-jeff-atwood](/questions/tagged/do-not-show-to-jeff-atwood)

Comment: I like how you just TOTALLY STOLE THE IDEA I MENTIONED IN PRIVATE IM ;-)

Comment: You're so very welcome. I only did it because you're all out of stars at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

I originally came up with this as a throwaway joke a few days ago, but since you ask...

```
for(Question q : questions)
    q.deleted = !q.deleted;
```

You could flip the closed bit in addition to/instead of the deleted bit.

... or perhaps the community wiki bit.

Comment: OR ALL OF THEM!!!!!!

Comment: I'll be taking that day off.

Comment: More interesting if you also swap userids

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade CAPTCHAs to test basic English spelling and grammar. Keep the obscured text, so people can't just hook up existing grammar checking engines, but come up with your own images so you don't end up displaying `GBLI^24[phi]`.

Might as well spend April Fool's Day doing some actual quality control. Hm? No, I'm not annoyed by any of the posts I edit on SO, why?

Comment: Ooh ooh, how about CAPTCHAs that make you enter text that matches a regex?

Answer (score 4):

Zalgoize all questions and answers. Or even all text on the site.

Comment: Zalgoize? What is that?

Comment: @Borror0: Google "zalgo text" and you'll find a few generators like [this one](http://textozor.com/zalgo-text/). I̩̖̊̀t͔̪͠'̤͓͌̔͒ͅs̷̙̮̣̹̟̬͚̎͑̔́ͩ ͖̲̯̹͉ͭ̃ͯ́̑͢ͅg͉͓͉̱̜r̬̻ͭ̾̎̔͒̾͘ê̈́͏̯̞a͕͗̌͘ͅt̅͋ͦ̍͘!̭̣̟̫͍̃̏ͯ̈́

Comment: Oh! So *that's* what it's called! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Simple version:

1. Make downvotes cost 1/2 the user's rep.

Extended edition:

1. Make downvotes cost 1/2 the user's rep.
2. Display a notification thanking the user for donating 1/2 their rep to the Jon Skeet foundation for terminally hopeless programmers (or some more believable fake charity incl. a link to fake site)
3. Award a funny 'Philanthropist' badge to anyone who loses over 1k rep as a result over the course of the day.

(Recalc at the end of the day, of course.)

Comment: Reducing or eliminating the vote quota and forcing users to "buy" votes (up or down) would also be interesting...

Answer (score 4):

Kitten macro every title.  Choose a variety of kitten related images that are short and wide, and use them as the background for the question title.  Use a modulo of the post number so the same image is served with any given question.

Iconic cat images (leaping through the grass, ceiling cat, etc) as well as moving gifs of dancing cats would give each question just the right spice it needs to encourage more upvotes.

It should also lesson people's stress as they blow past deadlines at work due to their diligence here.

Answer (score 4):

Claim that you have lost all the source code for the last ~2 years and revert the site to its design and functionality as it was at the moment it left the private beta.

I miss close/reopen wars

Answer (score 4):

Announcement of Stack overflow email accounts. Gmail started years ago on April first, and just like taking over ee, Stack Exchange is now targeting google, starting with email.

Similar to personal urls on careers, people would have to claim/reserve their email, so there would be a land ruch on them. We can make their experience more interesting by claiming that the first three names they chose are taken, and recommending jonskeet with a random eight digit number appended.

Answer (score 3):

How about Matrix SO?

[image: Matrix SO]

Here is a quick demo

```
javascript:document.body.style.background="url('http://steve.files.wordpress.com/2006/03/Matrix%20tut%202.jpg')";document.body.style.color='white';void(0);
```

Type this in your browser address bar.

It needs improvement though.

Comment: Needs moving characters, of course! ;-)

Comment: @Arjan jQuery will solve it for us.

Comment: That quick demo is not moving, and it makes the text very hard to read...

Comment: @Arjan I know,thats why I said it needs improvement.

Answer (score 3):

#### Tag "autocorrect"

How about messing with the tags users choose to apply? For example, any time someone submits a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) question on SO, display [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) when the page loads. On Cooking, you could do [butter] → [margarine]; on Unix and Linux, [kde] → [gnome].

#### Tag confirmation

If the "autocorrect" seems too disruptive to the user experience, add a confirmation page instead, with messages like...

- "Have you tried Eclipse?" for all [netbeans] questions on SO
- "Salad, huh? Do you have any questions about chocolate? C'mon, live a little!" for [salad], [tomatoes], &c. on Cooking
- "Mint, huh? Are you sure you don't want to try [a *real* distro](http://fedoraproject.org/)?" for [mint] on Unix/Linux

#### Meta

Meta sites should get to share in the fun! Let's skip all that pesky "discussion" and "thought" for one day by automatically attaching [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) to every post.

Also, there are already some restricted and some required tags on metas. How about deploying new ones? Perhaps "deferred" could become [status-six-to-eight-weeks] and "support" could become [plzsendtehfaqz]? Next year, new restricted/required tags could even sprout up on the main sites!

Comment: The "tag autocorrect" is too much of an invasion in the workflow IMO, but the two other suggestions are great.

Answer (score 3):

Cash in on the Twitter revolution by adding a [Dickbar](http://encodedrecords.com/dickbar/). Trending topics will keep users of Stack Exchange up to date on current happenings in the Twitterverse, such as what color everyone's underwear is and things celebrities hate. Plus, it's another thing to [monetize](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81173/careers-2-0-featured-listing-web-company-needs-successor-for-retiring-unicorns/81199#81199).

[image: Screenshot]

[(Explanation)](http://scripting.com/stories/2011/03/06/whatIsADickbar.html)

Answer (score 2):

Only allow comments shorter than 15 characters and questions or answers shorter than 30.

Comment: SO > Tw[i](http://# "Good job breaking it, hero.")tter

Answer (score 2):

On entering of a special keyword, make everything fall to the bottom of the screen, like [this](http://mrdoob.com/projects/chromeexperiments/google_gravity/) (requires Chrome or Chrome plug-in for other browsers). Depends on compatability and viability across browsers.

Comment: Wow... that's awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Since all sites are integrated, "seemingly" pull out information from careers.SO about current employer, send random warning (alert on top, something along the lines of

- "You really should be working."
- "What will the folks at [Current_Employer_Name] think of this?"
- "Suspicious activity detected, contacting [Current_Employer_Name] HR."

Comment: mmm, this has the potential to do too much damage to the trust people have in the site. Too brutal for an April Fools' joke IMO

Comment: @Pekka I'd think on that day, most people would get it's a joke. Plus, personally I don't disclose my current employer's name, so I'd be warned that "----- HR is getting contacted" would be obviously fake (and funny).

Answer (score 2):

How about a blog post to claim that StackExchange has been acquired by Facebook ?

Answer (score 2):

A nice easy one - switch to Sketchy theme for the day :)

Comment: Hat-tip to [tombull89](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/557286#557286)

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with the [answer for anonymous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81173/careers-2-0-featured-listing-web-company-needs-successor-for-retiring-unicorns/81201#81201) user names and user images, but adding also an experiment, by hiding the reputation, tags, recent questions/answers, bio, etc.; **basically no Profile/Users pages**.

Everything will continue to work the same (unless you will also add some random unicorns.. like everywhere), just nobody will be able to see who is who behind the answers/questions. Every user should be able to see their own points and profile page though, since not showing the votes for questions/answers is not an option as it might affect the overall quality of Q/A that day.

With this little experiment maybe Jon Skeet will stop getting upvotes for his unfinished answers for at least a day.. :) Also it would be fun to see the leagues the day after and how the top users were affected by this. Many believe that high-ranked users are getting more points just because they are high-ranked, so let's put it to a [test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythBusters).

Answer (score 2):

A site-wide **summon (Jon Skeet) button**, just like Batman's bat signal. It produces various fun interactions, like:

- a blank answer generated into your question with the text "pending Jon Skeet".
- a message indicating that Jon Skeet is busy at the moment "Please wait while Jon Skeet, finishes his call | returns from the moon | eats his pizza | flushes | etc."
- Show random facts from Jon Skeet facts on meta [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)
- etc.

(Feel free to update this list with other suggestions).
A designer could have some fun with this.

Answer (score 1):

Vaguely inspired from [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=status-declined%20feature-request) list.

- Private messaging: let anyone @ anyone (shows in the notification bar)
- Rep transfer: make people think they can transfer rep between sites (provide a fake exchange rate too :)
- Pretend to open-source something, provide code with subtle errors :)
- DIY colour schemes (i.e. not themes, people change individual colours)
- Add some new pluralization bugs
- Pretend to let people buy 'rep-boost' - you get double rep for any upvotes for a limited period
- Temporarily add some esoteric formatting option (`<blink>` :)
- Something like [this](http://erkie.github.com/)? (more of an Easter egg than an April Fools)
- Reverse the infamous enter-to-submit-comment functionality, randomly (*ducks*)

Answer (score 1):

Launch a new SE site for questions pertaining to life as a professional clown

**Clown Overflow**

[image]

**Top Questions**

- How do you cope with long shifts as a clown
- Recommendations for top quality clown car
- How to tell your family you want to become a clown

Comment: I don't see the joke. This is a perfectly valid StackExchange site. Even the example questions make sense. You don't think professional clowns exist?

Comment: @fretje, sorry, my mistake.  Meant to post it in area 51.

Comment: @fretje I believe this request is redundant; we already have a *clown overflow* and we're all on it right now.

Comment: Hey everybody... stop laughing with clowning! This is serious business! As a matter of fact, is there already a proposition for circus arts in general? Let's check it out...

Comment: [Olrightie](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/1044/shouldnt-we-add-everything-circus-related-to-this-proposal)!

Answer (score 1):

Dual Screen Stack Overflow Easter Egg:

Shifted off the main content in the browser window by about 1200 pixels shows all the related and linked questions in a summary view.  So the total content is about 2400 wide, the main content on the left half, and the additional content on the right half, with a large enough whitespace gap in between that people won't see it unless they have their window stretched very wide.  Pull the browser window open wide enough and you can see the question and answers on the left as normal, and the blurbs for the linked and related questions on the right.

Enabled by konami code or other typical easter egg enabler.

Comment: This could be combined with some Newegg or Dell ad for a cheap 2nd screen, if they are in to that! (Getting a browser window to position off screen might be hard for some browsers, like Safari on a Mac, if I recall correctly...)

Comment: @Arjan I worded that incorrectly.  I meant to indicate that the same browser window holds all the content, but if you don't open the window wide enough you won't see the new content off to the right.  It won't necessarily appear off screen, or require the window to be off screen, merely that the content is, say, 2400 pixels wide, but most people only open it to 1200 pixels wide, so they won't see the content between 1200 and 2400.

Comment: Aha, okay! Still, I would not mind if SE would earn some bucks with ads related to any April 1st joke.

Answer (score 1):

Put an ad on the site. And when I say "ad" I mean AD. One of those skins that are so popular now. Adblock doesn't block it because you actually make it the background image. Maybe an ad for Keeping Up With the Khardasians or something.

Comment: or -shudder- jersy shore. something like the http://www.aol.co.uk/ homepage does?

Comment: What's "Keeping Up With the Khardasians"? No matter. An ad for the hyphen site would be far scarier.

Comment: I read that as "Keeping Up With The [Cardassians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardassian)."

Answer (score 1):

Turn SO into an old-skool BBS.

Text mode console screen, preferably black background with white or green text for authenticity.

Would look something like this:

```
Welcome to StackOverflow. You are logged in as Spudley.
Please enter a command to continue.
Example commands: 'listquestions [active|featured|hot]', 'showquestion <id>', 'askquestion'
Type 'help' for more.

>_
```

Comment: Heh, balpha can be the first kid on the block to [actually succeed](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/288138#288138) at [creating this](http://so.mrozekma.com/unix-fuse.png). [Sigh](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/246218#246218).

Answer (score 1):

Calculate **all reputation values** on the site relative to Jon Skeet.

**Any other day**

> Skeet 285,539
>   Me  6,811

**On April 1**

> Skeet 100%
>   Me 2.39%

You could throw a client script in place to effect this without affecting the server code base.

Answer (score 0):

Grant everyone the precognitive badge for the day.

Answer (score 0):

Close meta. Link back to uservoice.

Answer (score 0):

It'd take a bit to do, but basically let everyone have diamond moderator privileges and run free. It's a joke that creates itself :)

Of course, you'd want to make a backup before and restore the backup afterwards, as well as put up a banner explaining that any questions asked will not be there tomorrow and also of course explaining that everyone has diamond unicorn powers.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81173/careers-2-0-featured-listing-web-company-needs-successor-for-retiring-unicorns/81193#81193

Comment: @wai I don't mean making users think they have diamond power, I mean actually giving it to each and every user :) Except for maybe the email visibility part. Wouldn't want people to see that

Answer (score 0):

To join in with the Paywall jokes, a Paywall on answers from people with over 1k rep.

But my original idea was instead of "1 other answers" replace it with "Jon Skeet already beat you to it." Or your high ranking username of choice (or even, the username of the people who actually did beat you to it.)

Answer (score 0):

Change the FAQ displayed to new users and claim that all questions must be written as answers as in Jepordy.

Prevent everyone with 10k or more to answer questions until one hour have passed since the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a new feature - answer tagging.

Just like questions, answers can now be given up to five tags.

Answer (score -1):

Put a Katamari button on every page of the site.

http://kathack.com/