# What's the purpose of "views" count in user's profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, views

On any SE universe site I'm registered my user page displays "views" right next to the number of reputation points.

What's the use of those "views" counter? I mean, okay, someone viewed my user page N+P times, so what? How does this help anyone in asking questions and getting answers?

Comment: Obviously, this sort of ego-stroking fluff was included in anticipation of the eventual [integration with Facebook](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81173/careers-2-0-featured-listing-web-company-needs-successor-for-retiring-unicorns/81175#81175). In the future, all things will be Facebook, and Facebook will be all things.

Comment: @gno, and all things will SUCK.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesnt... we all just love statistics, how does location/age/name/member for/last seen/openid/site or the customisable about me section help get questions answered?

It doesn't.. It's just nice to know.

Comment: It's like the `${count}` people were looking at your profile on LinkedIn emails... I don't really care... But gosh darn it I click through every time to see who it was... And get ticked off every time when the "`${bigwigTitle}`  from `${superExcitingIndustry}`" is the one viewer they hold back from me without paying for "pro" :-P