# Does "user profile views" contain/constitute the <repeat views from SO users> and <views from unregistered viewers>?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, views

I referred the "profile views" question related to [purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83142/whats-the-purpose-of-views-count-in-users-profile), [self view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122169/does-the-number-of-views-on-an-so-question-exclude-my-own-views) and [narcissism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12744/does-user-profile-views-include-narcissism); but couldn't find the answer.

1. Are repeat views from SO users added to profile views ? If yes then
   at what frequency/interval they are added (i.e. per minute, per day,
   per week) ?
2. If a profile is viewed by unregistered SO viewer, will it be added ?

Comment: Common sense tells me it's the number of users who viewed your profile but it might also be the number of unique IP views like question views. Official answer will be awesome.

Comment: See this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87092/dissecting-the-stack-overflow-views-counter

Comment: Same strategy like [question views](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-does-stack-overflow-calculate-the-number-of-views-in-a-question)

Comment: Some investigating gives me this: The views are cached or something and do not update. I created an account on History.SE and got 0 views, even when viewing from a proxy and whatnot.