# How does SO calculate user views of a question? 

Tags: discussion, views

How is the quantity of views a question has received calculated by Stack Overflow?

Does the site always check the user's IP Address in the database?

Comment: Are you referring to the number of times a user's profile has been viewed? The count of user visits to the site? Views of a question? Or something else?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129740/does-user-profile-views-contain-constitute-the-repeat-views-from-so-users-an http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132688/how-are-profile-views-counted

Comment: @razlebe I have updated the question..?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87092/dissecting-the-stack-overflow-views-counter

Comment: Thanks Vishal - I've made a further minor edit as a result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite a duplicate, but a fellow MSO user posted an interesting writeup about this at [Dissecting the Stack Overflow views counter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87092/dissecting-the-stack-overflow-views-counter). Excerpt:

> From what I can tell there is now a JavaScript section in each answer page (used to be CSS in 2008):
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="/posts/3590653/ivc/a947"></script>
> <noscript>
>     <div><img src="/posts/3590653/ivc/a947" class="dno" alt=""></div>
> </noscript>
> ```
>
> The last part of the URL - **a947** - seems to be dynamically generated. It is changed every 15-20 minutes and is **the same for all questions and presumably users** (I tried anonymous access, changing my IP address, it stays the same during the interval).