# What are the steps for recalling a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderators

After a site is graduating, its moderators appear to be elected for life or until they step down.

What are the steps for recalling a moderator that the site's users no longer believe represent the site's best interests?

Comment: I see you're trying to recall a moderator.  You should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: Seriously, though, do you believe we're in such a position now (i.e. we have a moderator behaving badly), or is this just a hypothetical?

Comment: Related - [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867)

Comment: Is this somehow different from the dozen posts we already have about "what should I do if a mod is terrible"?

Comment: Appears to be in relation to this issue on [gaming.se]: [Is it okay to edit and completely delete my question to ask your own?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3182/is-it-okay-to-edit-and-completely-delete-my-question-to-ask-your-own/)

Comment: Well, lacking any response to my last comment, I voted to close as a duplicate

Comment: I did [suggest a moderator recall election a few months ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81173/careers-2-0-featured-listing-web-company-needs-successor-for-retiring-unicorns/81710#81710), and even got eight upvotes. (Pay no attention to the fact that it was on the "suggest an April Fool's joke" post.)

Comment: Aw hell, what did I do now?

Comment: Okay, voting to reopen this for real because someone else already cast a reopen vote (see [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126293/is-there-a-mod-impeachment-process#comment341957_126293) for background).

Answer (score 13):

The best way to recall a moderator is to email team@stackoverflow.com (or team@[sitename].com), with the following details:

1. A detailed description of the behavior that you consider "not in the best interests of the site," along with the appropriate links to the posts illustrating such behavior.
2. A statement explaining why you believe the behavior is not in the best interest of the site, and why it is severe enough to warrant a recall.

Of course, before you do that, you might want to post a question on the specific site meta about the moderator and their actions, and see if the moderator is willing to engage in discussion about the behavior, or provide an explanation.

Moderators are elected by the community; this is a representative democracy.  To avoid moderators' decision-making process from being influenced by the need to constantly be re-elected each year, the position is (more or less) a permanent one, for as long as the moderator is willing and able to perform their duties adequately.

Moderators do not set policy; rather, they enforce the policy that is set forth by a process of community consensus and dictates by the SE staff.

Comment: SE 2.0 email address for the team is team+[sitename]@stackexchange.com.

Comment: @AnnaLear umm ... what about seasonedadvice and askdifferent, etc? I thought that's what Robert Harvey meant. Also, didn't know they wanted to plus differentiate, that's cool too. (yay gmail!)

Comment: @jcolebrand Sure, but you can't email team@programmers.stackexchange.com far as I know, and Robert didn't cover those sites.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was ambiguous, and was curious if they had secured routing for those.

Comment: @TheUnhandledException Probably should have said this last year, but the question doesn't mention any specific moderators or actions.  Yes, I had an ulterior motive when I asked it, but I expected the question to stand on its own merits unrelated to whatever squabble I was having at the time. One reason being because this isn't the first time I've seen moderators doing something that I believed was detrimental to the site.

Comment: Fair point @Powerlord. I removed my comment.